# filtering and sorting xml data by date in vb.net

Tags: asp.net, xml, vb.net, gridview

Ultimately, I'm trying to find a way to successfully sort and filter my xml data in a gridview display.

I have an xml sheet like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?>
<Notification>
  <Info>
    <Event>Template</Event>
    <Date>1899/01/01</Date>
  </Info>
  <Info>
    <Event>picnic</Event>
    <Date>2016/07/15</Date>
  </Info>
  <Info>
    <Event>party</Event>
    <Date>2015/10/29</Date>
  </Info>
</Notification>
```

That I need to filter and sort into an asp.net gridview on two different pages. On one page I keep a large record of all events and allow the addition, update, and deletion of records.  The second gridview is in the corner of my main page that should show current/upcoming events.  I define them like so (the 2nd one has smaller size dimensions, but that's the only difference):

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server"   HeaderStyle-ForeColor="#FF5A09" RowStyle-ForeColor="#FF9900" 
        AutoGenerateColumns="false"  BorderWidth="2px" 
        Width="1294px" Height="350px" AllowPaging="true" 
        OnPageIndexChanging="OnPageIndexChanging" AllowSorting="true" > 

 <Columns >
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Event" HeaderText="Event" ItemStyle-Width="150"  />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Date" HeaderText="Date" ItemStyle-Width="150" />
            <asp:CommandField ShowEditButton="True" ItemStyle-Width="30"/>
            <asp:CommandField ShowDeleteButton="True" ItemStyle-Width="30"/>

 </Columns>
```

I'm using this vb.net function to bind my xml data to my gridview

```
Private Sub BindGrid()

        Dim ds As New DataSet
        ds.ReadXml(Server.MapPath("~/Event_Info.xml"))
        GridView1.DataSource = ds
        GridView1.DataBind()
        GridView1.HeaderRow.TableSection = TableRowSection.TableHeader

    End Sub
```

My problem is that whenever I read the xml data, or try loading it with `Dim doc as XDocument=XDocument.Load("Path to my xml")`, the data read in is a string in the date column, so the only way I could find to sort them is by changing up my BindGrid() function like so:

```
Private Sub BindGrid()

            Dim ds As New DataSet
            ds.Tables[0].DefaultView.Sort = "Date desc"
            ds.ReadXml(Server.MapPath("~/Event_Info.xml"))
            GridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0].DefaultView
            GridView1.DataBind()
            GridView1.HeaderRow.TableSection = TableRowSection.TableHeader

        End Sub
```

This allowed me to sort if I only entered the date yyyy/mm/dd, but my add, delete, and update functions were no longer working.

if you want to see them, I will post them here, but **you could probably skip over this bit**: The Button_click here at the top is for adding a record to the gridview

```
   Protected Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    BindGrid()
    Dim oDs As DataSet = GridView1.DataSource
    Dim oDr As DataRow = oDs.Tables(0).NewRow
    oDr("Event") = TextBox1.Text
    oDr("Date") = TextBox2.Text

    oDs.Tables(0).Rows.Add(oDr)
    oDs.WriteXml(Request.PhysicalApplicationPath + "Event_Info.xml")
    BindGrid()

    TextBox1.Text = String.Empty
    TextBox2.Text = String.Empty

End Sub

Protected Sub GridView1_RowDeleting(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewDeleteEventArgs) Handles GridView1.RowDeleting
    BindGrid()
    Dim oDs As DataSet = GridView1.DataSource
    oDs.Tables(0).Rows(GridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).DataItemIndex).Delete()
    oDs.WriteXml(Request.PhysicalApplicationPath + "Event_Info.xml")
    BindGrid()
End Sub


Protected Sub GridView1_RowEditing(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewEditEventArgs) Handles GridView1.RowEditing
    GridView1.EditIndex = e.NewEditIndex
    BindGrid()
End Sub


Protected Sub GridView1_RowCancelingEdit(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewCancelEditEventArgs) Handles GridView1.RowCancelingEdit
    GridView1.EditIndex = -1
    BindGrid()
End Sub


Protected Sub GridView1_RowUpdating(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewUpdateEventArgs) Handles GridView1.RowUpdating
    ' Get the new values from the GridView controls
    Dim i As Integer = GridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).DataItemIndex
    Dim n As String = CType(GridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(0).Controls(0), TextBox).Text
    Dim rn As String = CType(GridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(1).Controls(0), TextBox).Text

    GridView1.EditIndex = -1
    BindGrid()
    ' Update the XML file using the new values

    Dim oDs As DataSet = GridView1.DataSource
    oDs.Tables(0).Rows(i).Item(0) = n
    oDs.Tables(0).Rows(i).Item(1) = rn
    oDs.WriteXml(Request.PhysicalApplicationPath + "Event_Info.xml")
    BindGrid()
End Sub
```

**End the skip bit**

I also have no idea how to successfully filter the data on the main page so that it shows only current and future events.  I've tried to find ways to apply a "where" clause of sorts on the date, but have been unsuccessful

Edit: marked a section as code that I forgot to mark as code

Comment: Start by Writing the schema to the xml file so it will include the Date as an actual date.  Then when you read the file it will also be a Date : oDs.WriteXml(Request.PhysicalApplicationPath + "Event_Info.xml",XmlWriteMode.WriteSchema).  Also fix GridView1_RowUpdating so you are writing a DateTime to the 2nd column instead of a string.  the textbox should be a string bu not the DataTable or DGV.

Comment: @jdweng Thanks, this helped me figure out how to write to schema, and saved me a step in solving some issues in this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution to my problem. I needed to be using dataviews instead of datasets to alter, sort, and filter my data.

My bindgrid function became this:

```
Private Sub BindGrid()

        Dim ds As New DataSet
        ds.ReadXml(Server.MapPath("~/Event_Info.xml"))
        Dim myView As New DataView

        myView = ds.Tables(0).DefaultView

        myView.Sort = "Date desc"

        GridView1.DataSource = myView

        GridView1.DataBind()


    End Sub
```

Note this larger change meant that my add/delete/update functions had to change.  I ended up writing them like this if anyone wants to see them:

```
Protected Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

        BindGrid()
        Dim dv As DataView = GridView1.DataSource
        Dim oDr As DataRowView = dv.AddNew()
        oDr("Event") = TextBox1.Text
        oDr("Date") = TextBox2.Text
        oDr.EndEdit()

        dv.DataViewManager.DataSet.WriteXml(Request.PhysicalApplicationPath + "Event_Info.xml", XmlWriteMode.WriteSchema)
        dv.Sort = "Date desc"
        BindGrid()

        TextBox1.Text = String.Empty
        TextBox2.Text = String.Empty

    End Sub

    Protected Sub GridView1_RowDeleting(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewDeleteEventArgs) Handles GridView1.RowDeleting
        BindGrid()
        Dim oDv As DataView = GridView1.DataSource
        oDv.Delete(GridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).RowIndex)
        oDv.DataViewManager.DataSet.WriteXml(Request.PhysicalApplicationPath + "Event_Info.xml", XmlWriteMode.WriteSchema)
        oDv.Sort = "Date desc"
        BindGrid()
    End Sub

Protected Sub GridView1_RowUpdating(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewUpdateEventArgs) Handles GridView1.RowUpdating
        ' Get the new values from the GridView controls
        Dim i As Integer = GridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).DataItemIndex
        Dim n As String = CType(GridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(0).Controls(0), TextBox).Text
        Dim rn As String = CType(GridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(1).Controls(0), TextBox).Text

        GridView1.EditIndex = -1
        BindGrid()
        ' Update the XML file using the new values

        Dim oDv As DataView = GridView1.DataSource
        oDv.DataViewManager.DataSet.Tables(0).Rows(i).Item(0) = n
        oDv.DataViewManager.DataSet.Tables(0).Rows(i).Item(1) = rn
        oDv.DataViewManager.DataSet.WriteXml(Request.PhysicalApplicationPath + "Event_Info.xml", XmlWriteMode.WriteSchema)
        BindGrid()
    End Sub
```

Of course, as was suggested in the comments, I defined an xml schema to ensure that the date column would be written into/read from the xml data as a date

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema id="EventsSchema"
    targetNamespace="http://tempuri.org/EventsSchema.xsd"
    elementFormDefault="qualified"
    xmlns="http://tempuri.org/EventsSchema.xsd"
    xmlns:mstns="http://tempuri.org/EventsSchema.xsd"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
>

  <xs:element name="Notification">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>

        <xs:element name="Info" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>

              <xs:element name="Event" type="xs:string"></xs:element>
              <xs:element name="Date" type="xs:dateTime"></xs:element>

            </xs:sequence>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>

      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```